# Get sum of values based on the value of 2 other date related columns

Tags: mysql

Given the sample data in the screenshot below, would it be possible in mysql to return a sum of values from `monthly_amount` only where the values are before this month.  I used a join to pull this data.  The 5 left columns are from one table, and the rest are from another.

The issue I'm running into is, lets say its April of 2015, I can't just do a sum `WHERE goal_year <= 2015 AND month_id_FK <= 4`, or else I'll get only those 4 months from both years, when in that scenario, I really want all the months from 2014, plus the 4 months from 2015.

I could handle this in PHP, but I wanted to first see if there would be a way to do this in mysql?

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Never, never paste your schema and your table's dump as a picture. Yes, it's faster, but it's disrespect for those who'll read your question

Comment: I had no idea.  What would be the appropriate alternative?  I tried to paste in the actual data but the formatting was out of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
WHERE Goal_Year*100+month_id_FK <= 201504
```

alternatively:

```
WHERE
    GOAL_YEAR < 2015 OR
    (GOAL_YEAR = 2015 and month_id_FK <= 4)
```

Comment: your first solution works!  I didn't try the second one.  Thank you!

Comment: actually, I spoke too soon.  It works as long as your month is in a 2 digit format.  Otherwise its comparing 201504 with 20154.

Comment: year * 100+month should work for both single and double digit months. 2015*100+4 = 201504. 2015*100+11 = 201511. Just make sure that both year and month are integers to start with. Otherwise do: (GOAL_YEAR+0)*100+(month_id_FK+0). The second solution that I posted might be slightly faster though, because it would allow mySQL to use an index on year or month.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(monthly_amount) from table where goaldate<(SELECT CURDATE())
```

this is not the actual query for your table..but if you do like this you will get the answer

you need the sum of monthly amount where the date is before current-date means today.
then you can just compare the currentdate with goal date